# MySQL Triggers before update error (Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'workflow_id' in 'NEW')

Tags: mysql, windows-7, triggers

Here's my schema that contains my tables, sample data and the trigger that causing the error. Basically, we're writting any change to the workflow_id to the log table. Except that some of the workflow_id are automatic, meaning that if we change the id to 2, the trigger will automatically change the id to 3 :

```
    CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `tsttrigger` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
    USE `tsttrigger`;
    -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.13, for Win32 (x86)
    --
    -- Host: localhost    Database: tsttrigger
    -- ------------------------------------------------------
    -- Server version   5.6.15

    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
    /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
    /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
    /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `submission`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `submission`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `submission` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `workflow_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `fk_table1_table2_idx` (`workflow_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_workflow_id` FOREIGN KEY (`workflow_id`) REFERENCES `workflow` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `submission`
    --

    LOCK TABLES `submission` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `submission` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `submission` (`id`, `workflow_id`, `description`) VALUES (1,1,'testing status'),(2,3,'new test');
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `submission` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
    /*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
    /*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
    /*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
    /*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
    /*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
    /*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
    /*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
    /*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
    DELIMITER ;;
    /*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `before_update_submission` BEFORE UPDATE ON `submission` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN


        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempTbl;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTbl AS 
            SELECT wf.id, wf.allow_status, wf.active
            from workflow as wf
            join submission as sub on wf.id = NEW.workflow_id
            where sub.id = NEW.id
            order by wf.allow_status;

        SET @Is_Auto_Count = (SELECT COUNT(active) FROM tempTbl WHERE active = TRUE);

        IF @Is_Auto_Count = 1 THEN

            insert into submission_log (id, workflow_id, description)
            values(NEW.id, NEW.workflow_id, NEW.description);

            SET NEW.workflow_id = (SELECT allow_status FROM tempTbl WHERE active = TRUE);


            insert into submission_log (id, workflow_id, description)
            values(NEW.id, NEW.workflow_id, NEW.description);

        ELSEIF @Is_Auto_Count = 0 THEN

            insert into submission_log (id, workflow_id, description)
            values(NEW.id, NEW.workflow_id, NEW.description);

        ELSEIF @Is_Auto_Count > 1 THEN

            SET @msg = 'There is more than one automated destination for this status';
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;

        END IF;
    end */;;
    DELIMITER ;
    /*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
    /*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
    /*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
    /*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `submission_log`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `submission_log`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `submission_log` (
      `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `workflow_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `submission_log`
    --

    LOCK TABLES `submission_log` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `submission_log` DISABLE KEYS */;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `submission_log` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `workflow`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `workflow`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `workflow` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `allow_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `workflow`
    --

    LOCK TABLES `workflow` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `workflow` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `workflow` (`id`, `allow_status`, `active`) VALUES (1,2,0),(2,3,1),(3,4,0),(4,5,0),(5,6,1),(6,99,0);
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `workflow` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;

    --
    -- Dumping events for database 'tsttrigger'
    --

    --
    -- Dumping routines for database 'tsttrigger'
    --
    /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

    /*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
    /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
    /*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

    -- Dump completed on 2014-01-24 11:59:44
```

If you run the following update statement you'll get the error on the second automated status:

```
FLUSH TABLES;
truncate tsttrigger.submission_log;
select * from tsttrigger.submission;
select * from tsttrigger.workflow;

-- Id 1 not automated to next status 2
update tsttrigger.submission set workflow_id = 1
where id = 1;

-- Id 3 not automated to next status 4
update tsttrigger.submission set workflow_id = 3
where id = 1;

-- Id 2 is automated to next status 3 THISWORK BECAUSE OF FLUSH STATEMENT
update tsttrigger.submission set workflow_id = 2
where id = 1;

-- Id 5 is automated to next status 6 THIS WILL FAILED
update tsttrigger.submission set workflow_id = 5
where id = 1;

-- Id 1 not automated to next status 2
update tsttrigger.submission set workflow_id = 1
where id = 1;

SELECT * FROM tsttrigger.submission_log;
```

If I'm running the flush statement before each update, the error never appear and the triggers run perfectly.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, here the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/049d0/1).

Comment: Tks for your update. On version 5.5.32 the triggers works perfectly. But if you use version 5.6.6 of MySQL in the SQL Fiddle, we  get the error. It seem there's an issue with the latest version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is specifically with the following statement (in MySQL 5.6.6 m9):

```sql
SET NEW.`workflow_id` := (SELECT `allow_status` FROM `tempTbl` WHERE `active` = TRUE);
```

One possible workaround to avoid the problem is to do something like:

```sql
...
DECLARE `_workflow_id` INT;
...
SET `_workflow_id` := (SELECT `allow_status` FROM `tempTbl` WHERE `active` = TRUE);
SET NEW.`workflow_id` := `_workflow_id`;
...
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08042/1)</kbd>